# MacBook Pro is not displaying Wi-Fi networks

Tags: wifi

Early 2010 MacBook Pro, with Yosemite is unable to lookup any Wi-Fi network all of a sudden.

Tried reseting [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

It shows Wi-Fi: Looking for Networks... and then Wi-Fi: On. Does not list the available Wi-Fi Networks

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try turn off WiFi, wait 2 minutes turn on again ?

Comment: Could you be precise?

Comment: Could you be more precise, is the WiFi working (scanning) but it can not find any networks ?

Comment: It shows `WiFi: Looking for Networks...` and then `WiFi: On`. Does not list the available WiFi Networks.

Comment: Specifically, which version of Yosemite are you on? (i.e. OS X 10.10.1, 10.10.2, 10.10.3, or 10.10.4?)

Comment: `10.10.4 (14E46)`

Comment: Try Apple Hardware Test (press D during boot) and also check if networks are shown in the Recovery partition (press cmd + R during boot)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it might be a bad Airport card, if you have the tools, open it up and then disconnect and reconnect the antennas connecting to the card. If that doesn't work, remove the card, clean the contacts with isopropyl alcohol on the card and then reinstall it. If that doesn't work, you'll need to buy a new card, specific for your model of MacBook.

Comment: I guess you are right.